# Unable to update records in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have `answers` table with fields `id` `player_id` `read_status`

I am trying to update `read_status`:

```
$this->Answer->updateAll(
    array(
        'Answer.' . "'" . $data['field'] . "'" => "'" . trim(base64_decode($data['option'])) . "'"
    ),
    array(
        'Answer.id' => trim(base64_decode($data['id']))
    )
);
```

The following fields are dynamic and coming from AJAX Request:

`$data['field']` contains `read_status`

`$data['option']` contains base64 encoded `yes`

`$data['id']` contains base64 encoded `id`

The error I am getting is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Answer.'read_status'' in 'field list'
>   SQL Query:

```
UPDATE
    `skii`.`answers` AS `Answer`
LEFT JOIN
    `skii`.`players` AS `Player` ON (`Answer`.`player_id` = `Player`.`id`)
SET
    `Answer`.`'read_status'` = 'yes'
WHERE
    `Answer`.`id` = 2
```

> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\pdo_error.ctp

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll be able to answer this yourself when you take a closer look at the error message and the `SET` part of the query.

Comment: @ndm I am really confused now! Been messing with it since long. Please help!

Comment: remove the double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the proble is that you are escaping the field name with single quotes:

> `Answer`.`'read_status'` = 'yes'

should be

> `Answer`.`read_status` = 'yes'

The following change should fix that:

```
$this->Answer->updateAll(
    array('Answer.' . $data['field'] => trim(base64_decode($data['option']))),
    array('Answer.id' => trim(base64_decode($data['id'])))
);
```

Comment: I recommend you at least read the answer I just wrote (asker and answerer).

Comment: i don't think it will update as value of field should be in '' if it is not an int type in updateAll() case

Comment: True, I just pointed out an easy fix, instead of suggesting using `save` or validating the input. Again, your answer offers a complete explanation, @AD7six

Answer (score 3):

### Don't do that

The conditions you're generating are:

```
WHERE
    `Answer`.`id` = 2
```

There is **no reason** to use updateAll for that, the primary use cases for updateAll are:

- Updating multiple records
- Updates by not-primary-key
- Updates such as incrementing a counter atomically

### Call save

Instead, just call saveField:

```
$this->Answer->id = $id;
$this->Answer->saveField($field, $val);
```

or save:

```
$this->Answer->id = $id;
$this->Answer->save(array($field => $val));
```

### Validate your inputs

If you choose to continue using the code in the question know that it is dangerous.

Feeding user input directly to updateAll allows for the possibility to inject arbitrary SQL. Ensure the data is the data you expect:

With the `updateAll` call there's nothing to prevents someone submitting as `$field`:

> "read_status = 'yes' AND correct ="

achieving this sql:

```
SET `Answer`.`read_status` = 'yes' AND correct = 'yes'
```

It is generally a bad idea to *ever* put user input in the key of a CakePHP model array (update, conditions, order) as the key is not expected to be potentially malicious by CakePHP and therefore not subject to the same escaping logic applied to values.

Therefore, escape all user input:

```
$ds = $this->Answer->getDatsource();

$id = (int)trim(base64_decode($data['id']));
$field = $this->Answer->escapeField((base64_decode($data['field']));
$val = $ds->value(trim(base64_decode($data['option']))), $field);
```

With the above logic and attempting the same injection as shown in the first example the result would be:

```
SET `Answer`.``read_status` = 'yes' AND correct =` = 'yes';
```

Which would simply fail rather than permit users to arbitrarily manipulate the database.

*Note that the base64 encoding, if it's been added as a "security" measure, does nothing.*

Comment: I should have been a little more specific, sorry, I was referring to the field/value part or updateAll of course.

Comment: in the update (first parameter) yes, as it's treated as an sql fragment. In the conditions (second parameter) no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$this->Answer->updateAll(
array(
    'Answer.' . $data['field']  => "'" . trim(base64_decode($data['option'])) . "'"
),
array(
    'Answer.id' => trim(base64_decode($data['id']))
)
);
```